# AWS SDK state machine returns response before completing the execution

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions, aws-sdk-net

I have an AWS state machine which calls the lambda function when executed. I used AWS StepFunctions SDK for .Net to execute the state machine. `StartExecution` method in the SDK return as soon as the state machine execution started. I want the function not return until state machine execution completes.

Answer (score 1):

`StartExecution` API is only supposed to start a state machine execution by returning an `executionArn` value if successful. To check the status of the execution you may use another API such as [DescribeExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html)

> This operation is eventually consistent. The results are best effort
>   and may not reflect very recent updates and changes.